# Background on website gets cut off

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage.

I had a picture as background until, on a bigger screen, I realized that it wasn't stretching as supposed.
The image was basically a gradient of colors, but I decided I could equally do it with css:s built-in gradient function.

The thing is though, that the background gets cut off. In the bottom I have a col-sm-12.text-center, and it's below this one that it cuts off.
At the bottom I have a footer so there is a white space between the end of the col-sm-12 and where the footer begins.

I have put on non-repeat on the background gradient since I don't want it to repeat obviously but to continue throughout the page.

I have searched but not found any answer to this problem.

I am suspecting that the col-sm-12 might be the problem but do you guys have any other sultion to this problem?

Comment: ahow your related css code

Comment: Yes I think the col-sm-12 is the problem as it gets locked at a certain width. Try removing the background from there and adding it to the <body> instead.

Answer (score 0):

for streching a background image use size: cover;

```
.my_bg_img  {
   background-image: url('./your_image.jpg');  
  background-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  height: 100%;
  widht: auto;
}
```

this fit the container  ...
if the container is too small remove col-sm-12 or change the related container (eg: body for sample)

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing in my Html.
In my CSS

```
body{
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro Light", sans-serif;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, black, white);
     background-size: cover;
     margin-bottom:10px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
```